# Use Material-UI Classes

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm currently struggeling with a problem and I can't seem to get it working. I'm using a own js file for declaring my themes. It looks something like this:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import * as variables from 'variables'
export const Theme = createMuiTheme({
typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
},
container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
},
content: {
    width: variables.contentWidth,
    minHeight: variables.contentMinHeight,
    backgroundColor: red, 
}
});
```

And then in my index.js I use the following code to try to implement the created theme. Most of the things also work, but I can't seem the container and context to get to display. 
There's just nothing; nothing on the screen and no errors in the console.
Note this isn't all the code but only the bit that doesn't work.

```
import * as themes from 'themes'
//Other Imports and definitions
render(){
   const { className } = this.props;
   console.log(this.props); //Returns something, so I know that this.props is defined
   return(
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={themes.Theme}>
          <Grid container className={classNames(themes.Theme.container, className)}>
             <Grid className={classNames(themes.Theme.content, className)}>
             </Grid>
          </Grid>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
   );
}
export default withStyles(themes.Theme, NameofTheClassThisIsIn);
```

If something of my code is missing please just ask.

Kind regards,
Herr Frodo

Comment: first after using wrapping the component with `withStyles` classes are exported as props as `classes` so you will be applying classes as `<Grid className={classNames(classes.content)}>`

Comment: I sadly only get the error message 
ReferenceError: classes is not defined
When I try this. I also tried to just use 
this.props.themes.Theme.content
before but this also throws th error above.

Comment: and I have not seen having a global class within createMuiTheme function, if I may ask do you want to export those classes as global ?

Comment: Yes, I do. I want to export them to later use in my index.js. Sorry for the confusion